# Reading excel file with pandas

Tags: python

I have tried to read an excel file using pandas however I haven't been able to. I am using python version 3.8 and still haven't been able to do it. I want to make the excel file a list in python and then use that list in an option box via tkinter. However without being able to read the file I cannot do this.

The code I'm using is:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel (r'downloads\Clients - Nybble HelpDesk.xlsx')
print (df)
```

The error I'm recieving is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Natasha\OneDrive - Nybble.co.uk LTD\Desktop\excel export.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Comment: You need to install pandas first

Comment: The error indicates that you do no have installed `pandas` package. You can create a virtual environment and install `pandas` using `pip install pandas`.

Comment: try `pip install pandas`. Or `pip install --user pandas` depending upon your python installation location and path.

Comment: I'm voting to close this, there are already plenty of resources available on this kind of error, and on the subject of installing modules.

Comment: While many people are suggesting to just `pip install pandas`, I would strongly recommend using virtual environments or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

In the command line try `pip install pandas` to install pandas first. Then re-run your code.

Other installation information is available here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/install.html

Answer (score 0):

you can save time by downloading the anacondas distribution and use the spyder IDE. This will prevent the need to install pandas and will come with a whole host of useful packages that you will likely use in your day to day.

See the link: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/tutorials/pandas/

Comment: `pip install pandas` is super easy and much easier then dealing with anaconda. I would not recommend anaconda as it is know for having issues.

Comment: _`pip install pandas` is super easy_ Isn't `conda install pandas` pretty easy, too? _and much easier then dealing with anaconda_ In what way? _I would not recommend anaconda as it is know for having issues._ What issues? I think using Conda is a good idea, especially for someone who is a beginner and on Windows.

Comment: Exactly, the whole point of downloading it is to save time without having to worry about dependencies. This is particularly an issue when you join a company with security restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

First install pandas. 
If you are using python shell then, open command prompt and type `pip install pandas`.
If you are using Anaconda then, open Conda Prompt and type `conda install pandas`.
You have your pandas library installed now.
Now for your code,

```
import pandas as pd
excel_file = 'filepath.xls'
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
print (df)
```

Now try it! and be sure to check the path of your file. Save the file in the same folder where you are saving the `.py` file.